# Indicate number of Tags in Tooltip

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, tooltips

When viewing the main questions page, questions have their tags listed below them.  Currently, when you hover the mouse over a tag, a tooltip comes up with information on the follower count, some options and if given a tag wiki summary.  It would be useful to be able to determine immediately just how many questions are tagged with that tag; I propose altering the tooltip to read something like "view 23 questions with the TAGNAME tag"; that is, to add the number of instances of that tag to the tooltip for the tag.

This would be useful to be able to view the relative popularity of the tag without needing to traverse any links, and should be relatively technically simple to implement; tag tooltip text could be cached and updated occasionally to obviate the need to query the DB for the number of tags on each pageload.

Comment: I understand the proposal, but I don't really understand why you think this would be beneficial. Why would it really help you to know the relative popularity of the tag? If it's something that you're interested in, you would click on it and browse the questions. If it's not, who cares how popular it is and how many questions it's been applied to?

Comment: @CodyGray: I would contend that it is no less useful than knowing the number of followers on a tag, which is already exposed, and I would argue that knowing how many questions are tagged with that tag is MORE important than knowing how many followers a tag has.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I wouldn't have understood a proposal to add the number of followers to the tooltip either. It all seems like unnecessary information to me.

Comment: I think that could be extended for entire site, specially at reviews page

Answer (score 5):

This is getting more important with suggested edits.  We need to be able to hover over a tag and see if it was 'made-up' or if it is an established tag.

Comment: just came to the same conclusion